# How to add borders to div without messing up the layout?

Tags: css, html, border, multiple-columns

I have the following elements:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar1"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3> 
            <p>Whatnot.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Following this style:

```
/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds all other divs~~ */
 #container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    /*border: 2px solid black;*/
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding: 0px 0px 100% 0px;
}
#content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebar2 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    /*border: 2px solid black;*/
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding: 0px 0px 100% 0px;
}
```

I am trying to achieve this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/QnRe4/

But as soon as I un-comment the borders it turns into this: http://jsfiddle.net/FZxPQ/

**** Solved ****

The border width was added to each element's total width making them too wide to fit in the container. Removing 2x the border width from each column's width solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/FZxPQ/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you add in the boarder, the size of the outer divs increased by 4, 2px on each size. So, your container needs to grow in size by 8px.

So change your container to:

```
 #container {
    width: 970px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/QnRe4/13/

Answer (score 7):

CSS [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the rescue! This property

> alters the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements

The `border-box` value means that

> the width and height properties include the padding and border

```
/* support Firefox, WebKit, Opera and IE8+ */
#container, #sidebar1, #sidebar2 {
         box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However, [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) is not 100% standardized.

As other answers have already mentioned the extra width which pushes the sidebars out of alignment is because the width calculation includes the *border width*. `box-sizing` simply tells the browser that an element with a given width/height should include any border and padding values into the final width/height calculations.

Comment: The disadvantage to this approach is browser-compatibility.  The code above will work on some modern browsers, but realistically you need to use vendor-prefixes to account for all current browsers.  Even the latest FireFox still needs -moz. (Source: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Comment: this is probably the answer the OP is looking for. @johnkavanagh - vendor prefixes aren't the end of the world, and apart from that browser compatibility is fine unless you plan to support IE6/IE7 (naaah... ;)).

Comment: For me `box-sizing` works in all browsers. Just need to add the vendor prefix for Firefox, which it isn't so bad. My limit is IE8, don't care about older browser.

Answer (score 3):

When you apply the borders, that goes outer the divs, so the sidebars will have 184px width which doesn't fits to the container. try addig `width: 176px`

http://jsfiddle.net/QnRe4/12/

```
#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 176px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding: 0px 0px 100% 0px;
}
```

Comment: another solution if you add the `box-sizing` property to your sidebars: [read more about this here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QnRe4/3/

What's happening is that your elements are losing their `block` display properties when you remove the borders.

So, adding `display: block` to those elements resolves that.

I've also adjusted your element's widths by 4px in width to retain the layout, since removing those borders essentially reduces the space that those elements occupy on-page.

Comment: Yes. Much better answer than mine. :)

Comment: I didn't know that the border's width was added to the element's total width. Thank you @jognkavanagh

Comment: No problem!  For reference, here's some more information on how the box model works: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html  Essentially: the width is made up of content-width + padding.  If you have borders, the size of these is added in addition to the width, so if you're using fixed-widths and borders, you have to account for the borders (or border removal) in the width.  Likewise if you changed the padding.